# subscript out of range VBA code

Tags: vba, range, out, subscript

Could anyone help me to figure out why this code erro is "subscript is out of range". (run time error 9)

```
Dim arrayU() As Variant
Dim arrayX() As Variant
Dim arrayW() As Variant
Dim LrowU As Integer
Dim LrowX As Integer
Dim LrowW As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim bed_in_use As Integer


   For i = 3 To LrowX
   For r = 3 To LrowW
   For j = 3 To LrowX

   If bed_in_use >= 24 Then Exit For

   If arrayX(i) = arrayW(r) Then
   bed_in_use = bed_in_use - 1
   If arrayX(i) = arrayU(j) Then
   bed_in_use = bed_in_use + 1

   Cells(i, "Y").Value = bed_in_use
    End If
    End If
```

Comment: That would depend on your declaration of the arrays.  Show the declaration lines.  As in `Dim arrayx(...`

Comment: Dim strDate
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim arrayU() As Variant
    Dim arrayX() As Variant
    Dim arrayW() As Variant
    Dim LrowU As Integer
    Dim LrowX As Integer
    Dim LrowW As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim bed_in_use As Integer

Comment: not in the comments please, put it in the original post.

Comment: You need to set the size of the Array.  Just before your loops you need to do this for all three. `ReDim ArrayX(3 to Lrowx) as Variant` do it for all three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx) for information about this error.

In your case i'd say it is the first option :

- You referenced a nonexistent array element.

Check if the values of **i**, **r** and **j** aren't larger than what the arrays where dimensioned for...

---

Either that or:

- You declared an array but didn't specify the number of elements.